# Highcharts: multiple series columns by year

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I want to render 2 column series grouping by year.

It works well if both series have data for all xAxis points (year).
For example [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/phpepe/cj1mokg7/1/) plots data for both series in 2012 and 2013 and works well.

But what happens of I remove 2013 from series 1 and 2012 for series 2, [this is the result](http://jsfiddle.net/phpepe/Lsj8Lngr/).

I know that adding `null` values and missing years will solve the problem, but may be there is another solution.

Comment: You should use [pointRange](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#plotOptions.series.pointRange) parameter http://jsfiddle.net/Lsj8Lngr/1/

Comment: Check out this demo which shows how to define a point in time for each datapoint specific: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/spline-irregular-time/

Comment: Thanks for your response ! I like Sebastian Bochan, solution..  And just another small detail, in you example the 2012 has space reserved for the second series. is there any way of removing the spaces if the series has no data for the same year ? thanks

Comment: The spacing can be control by groupPadding/ pointPadding globally, but set width for particular point is not possible. Btw mark my answer as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use pointRange parameter http://jsfiddle.net/Lsj8Lngr/1

```
 "column": {
    pointRange: 365 * 24 * 3600 * 1000,
  "colorByPoint": true,
  "grouping": true,
  "dataLabels": {
    "enabled": false,
    "crop": false
  }
},
```